# Date Formatting in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I'm writing in Classic ASP for a registration form, and would like to close the registration. I declared the closing date in the variable "closingdate", and have another variable which gets the current date.

```
dim closingdate : closingdate = "5/17/2014"
response.write("Closing date: " & closingdate & "<br>")

dim currentdate : currentdate = Date
response.write(currentdate)
response.write("<br>")

if (currentdate > closingdate) then 
  response.write("Registrations are closed")
else 
  response.write("Registrations are still open")
end if
```

The results given to me right now is the "Registrations are still open", despite me setting the closing date as a date that's a year before. Have I left out something here?

Comment: Formatting is to do with how a date/time is displayed. Comparing two dates has nothing to do with formatting. Always make sure before any comparison operation both values are "real" date/time values and not formatted date strings. Otherwise you're comparing a date/time value to a string which will give unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart , I followed the answer below by casting the string I declared into a Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try casting your string into a date first:

```
if (currentdate > cdate(closingdate)) then
  response.write("Registrations are closed")
else
  response.write("Registrations are still open")
end if
```

Comment: @kosherjellyfish Just to add to this, I would cast as soon as you create the date... `Dim closingdate : closingdate = CDate("5/17/2014")`.

Comment: @Paul is of course correct, casting sooner is preferable

Comment: Sorry, schudel - comment was supposed to be earmarked for OP. :o)

Comment: Try explaining your answer, remember we are creating answers for the community not just the OP.